# Set the value of the passed parameters for various types c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httprequest

I am trying to crate a generic image upload function, so i can use it for different classes containing different property names for FileContent, FileName and FileType.

This is what I have tried so far, but obviously this won't work since it's not setting the value of the passed parameters.

```
public static void StoreFile(this HttpRequestBase @this, byte[] fileContent, string fileName, string fileType)
    {
        if ((@this.Files != null) && (@this.Files.Count == 1))
        {
            var file = @this.Files[0];
            if ((file != null) && (file.ContentLength > 0))
            {
                var content = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                file.InputStream.Read(content, 0, file.ContentLength);
                fileContent = content;
                fileName = file.FileName;
                fileType = file.ContentType;
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there any way of passing an anonymous type or something that would help in this case?

Comment: Are you saying that you want the `StoreFile` method to actually modify the values of the parameters given so that they can be used elsewhere?

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne Yes indeed.

Comment: See this thread for more information about **passing by reference** and **passing by value**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555471/modify-method-parameter-within-method-or-return-result

Answer (score 1):

I believe your solution is changing your function declaration to read like such:

`public static void StoreFile(this HttpRequestBase @this,ref byte[] fileContent, ref string fileName, ref string fileType)`

Refer to ThePerplexedOne's comment [(or this)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-za/library/0f66670z.aspx) for why exactly this works.

Comment: It might be more appropriate to use `out` rather than `ref` in this case. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx

Comment: I was not aware of this. Agreed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to achieve this using Action Delegates:

This is your generic `StoreFile` method which would take 3 different action delegates as parameters.

```
public static void StoreFile<T>(this HttpRequestBase @this, T specificClassObject, Action<T, byte[]> setFileContent, Action<T, string> setFileName, Action<T, string> setFileType) where T : class
{
    if ((@this.Files != null) && (@this.Files.Count == 1))
    {
        var file = @this.Files[0];
        if ((file != null) && (file.ContentLength > 0))
        {
            var content = new byte[file.ContentLength];
            file.InputStream.Read(content, 0, file.ContentLength);
            setFileContent(specificClassObject, content);
            setFileName(specificClassObject, file.FileName);
            setFileType(specificClassObject, file.ContentType);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is how you would call `StoreFile` generic method for objects of different types:

```
// SpecificClass has properties byte[] PDFFileContent, string MyOrYourFileName and string ContentTypeWhatEver
myHttpRequestBaseObject.StoreFile<SpecificClass>(specificClassObject, (x, y) => x.PDFFileContent = y, (x, y) => x.MyOrYourFileName = y, (x, y) => x.ContentTypeWhatEver = y);
```