# Why the list passed in the parameter is not updated after calling the Filter() method?

Tags: c#, .net, list

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var b = new List<MyModel>
            {
                new MyModel { Id = 1},
                new MyModel { Id = 2},
                new MyModel { Id = 3},
            };
            var a = new List<int> { 1 };

            Filter(a, b);
        }

        private static void Filter(IEnumerable<int> a, List<MyModel> b)
        {
            b = b.Where(u => a.Contains(u.Id)).ToList();
        }
    }

    public class MyModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

I expect the list b to only contain the element with id 1. The list is not filtered after calling the Filter method.

Comment: And the `b` parameter is a value parameter in `Filter`. You're assigning back to the value, but that doesn't modify the value of the `b` local variable in `Main`.

Comment: For such little examples consider to add [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yHxK25), then it's easier to see, try, play, fix, etc.

Comment: You have to use `ref` if you want to modify `b` or another option is to call methods of passed instance to modify instance (e.g. `Clear()` + `Add()` will change local `b`).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555471/modify-method-parameter-within-method-or-return-result/556103

Comment: read about how the references are passed in .NET. You need to return the filtered collection or pass the reference (not the copy of the reference) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update your code a little bit

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var b = new List<MyModel>
    {
        new MyModel { Id = 1},
        new MyModel { Id = 2},
        new MyModel { Id = 3},
    };

    var a = new List<int> { 1 };
    b = Filter(a, b);
}

private static List<MyModel> Filter(IEnumerable<int> a, List<MyModel> b)
{
    return b.Where(u => a.Contains(u.Id)).ToList();
}
```

[`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8) method returns new `IEnumerable<MyModel>` and you should return this value, evaluated to list, from `Filter` method and assign back to `b` variable

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Pavel's excellent answer, this would also be a good time to learn the ref keyword:

```
private static void Filter(IEnumerable<int> a, ref List<MyModel> b)
{
    b = b.Where(u => a.Contains(u.Id)).ToList();
}
```

Adding ref to the parameter b in the Filter function means the List passed to the function can be modified in the function. In other words, the List will be changed in Main without having to set it to the return value of a function, as you were expecting it to work in your original code.